# Did the line about Krishna get altered in X-Men: Apocalypse?

Tags: dialogue, x-men-cinematic-universe, censorship, x-men-apocalypse

In the *X-Men: Apocalypse* trailer, we hear the following line being spoken by Apocalypse:

> I've been called many things in many lifetimes- Ra, Krishna, Yahweh."

But in theater I was not able to track any such dialogue mentioning Krishna.

Did this get altered in the final film due to the [recent controversy](http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/lord-krishna-as-a-villain-in-x-men-apocalypse-at-least-these-offended-hindus-think-so-x-men-apocalypse-trailer-watch/1/548677.html)? What was it replaced with? And is it only done for Indian versions?

Comment: Should it be moved to mythology.SE :P

Comment: @ABcDexter lol...

Comment: It was removed due to controversy, bad. There was no need for controversy

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Yes, dialogue referring to the Hindu God Krishna was removed from the final cut of the film.**

From [this article](http://www.thehansindia.com/posts/index/Hollywood/2016-05-27/Deleting-inappropriate-reference-to-Krishna-in-X-Men-Apocalypse-welcomed/230820) (which I've edited down somewhat);

> Hindus are thankful to 20th Century Fox and Director Bryan Singer for deleting reference to Lord Krishna in the movie “X-Men: Apocalypse”.
>    
>   Hindu statesman Rajan Zed wrote to 20th Century Fox in March last urging Singer and 20th Century Fox Chairman James N. Gianopulos to not have any inappropriate references to Lord Krishna in the final movie, unless those were true to the scriptures or based on scriptures.
>    
>   In a statement in Nevada today, he expressed thanks to Singer and Fox for deleting reference to Lord Krishna in the final movie, thus showing maturity and responsibility, and understanding the feelings of Hindu community.