# In Black Panther why does M'baku use this phrase?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, dialogue, black-panther

Why does M'Baku use this phrase ?

> Glory to HANUMAN

[image]

Some body says "He belongs to monkey tribe". Did they know about LORD HANUMAN?

Can we confirm what he actually says and why he says it?

Comment: If you are relying on subtitles, they MAY have been *interrpreted differently* for the intended audience.

Comment: no i just watch this scene nearly 10 times..for clarity..

Comment: It is Hanuman only but got censored in India, refer my answer for more details

Comment: He also wears a monkey mask for battle, and in a later scene says [we are vegetarians](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j45RULddbNc)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**In Black Panther why did M'Baku use the phrase “GLORY TO HANUMAN” ?**

Because it's their God in MCU. It's not from the comics and introduced only in the film but all references to Hanuman were censored from screenings of Black Panther in the India due to religious persons getting offended.

But this censorship even [angered many Indian fans too](http://indianexpress.com/article/trending/trending-in-india/black-panther-fans-in-india-angry-over-beeping-out-hanuman-reference-twitter-reactions-5073987/).

From [indianexpress](http://indianexpress.com/article/entertainment/hollywood/black-panther-hanuman-muted-not-cbfc-5075192/)

> While many felt that this was CBFC’s doing, our sources have told us that “it is not CBFC who muted the word Hanuman but it’s the producers of the movie in India who decided to do this.”

From [Wikia](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Hanuman):

> In the comics, Ghekre the Ape God is the central figure of the White Gorilla Cult, a religion banished from the Wakandan society but still practiced among the Jabari and led by M'Baku. Historically, Ghekre is a Baoulé deity worshipped in West Africa.

So they just changed the name to that of an Indian god.

**Did they know about our Indian gods?**

That we can't say yet, in MCU we know only about Hnauman being Wakanda god. And Indian gods getting mentioned and then censored in Hollywood is not so new concept:

[Did the line about Krishna get altered in X-Men: Apocalypse?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/53860/1190)

Comment: Why didn't they just use the name Ghekre, then?

Comment: @JAB I can only found speculation about it no official statement.

Comment: @JAB probably because Hanuman is probably the only monkey-god any Westerner is likely to recognize.